# how to use match against query for single letter or double letter

Tags: php, sql

I used the search query below for an on key up event

```
$query = "select * from employee where 
          match(first_name,last_name,batch,branch,city) 
          against ('+$data*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
          ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'Approval') desc,employee_id desc ";
```

but this query does not search records that have single character or double character - e.g.
first_name like aa,qa,qq,ansual

if i type "a" it will show only ansual records not aa.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the parameter `ft_min_word_len`, which is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len).

The default is 4, so words with 1, 2, or 3 characters not included in the full text index.  You will need to rebuild the index if you need this functionality.